# While trying to run my app,i am getting tis error. java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.TypeTranslatorImpl.<init>

Tags: android, kotlin

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.TypeTranslatorImpl.<init>(org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.util.ReferenceSymbolTable, org.jetbrains.kotlin.config.LanguageVersionSettings, org.jetbrains.kotlin.descriptors.ModuleDescriptor, kotlin.jvm.functions.Function0, boolean, org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.util.StubGeneratorExtensions, org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtFile, int, kotlin.jvm.internal.DefaultConstructorMarker)'
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.AbstractComposeLowering.<init>(AbstractComposeLowering.kt:165)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.ClassStabilityTransformer.<init>(ClassStabilityTransformer.kt:63)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.ComposeIrGenerationExtension.generate(ComposeIrGenerationExtension.kt:84)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.convertToIr$lambda$1(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:222)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.Psi2IrTranslator.generateModuleFragment(Psi2IrTranslator.kt:107)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.convertToIr(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:255)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.convertToIr(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:59)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.convertToIr(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:224)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli$default(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:47)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:168)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:53)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:100)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:46)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:460)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:62)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.doCompile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:476)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:399)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileNonIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:280)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:124)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:636)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1598)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Errors were stored into /Users/swatiagarwal/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication2/.gradle/kotlin/errors/errors-1703043942195.log
```

My gradle :

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version= '1.5.20'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10"

    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    // Add the Google services Gradle plugin
//    id("com.google.gms.google-services")
}
android {
    namespace 'com.delusion.tambola'
    compileSdk 34
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.delusion.tambola"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.7.10'
    }
//    kotlinOptions {
//
//    }
    // Suppress Compose Kotlin compiler compatibility warning
    tasks.withType(KotlinCompile).configureEach {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = '1.8'
            freeCompilerArgs += [
                    "-P",
                    "plugin:androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck=1.9.0"
            ]
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
        viewBinding true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.3.2'
    }
    /*packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }*/
}

dependencies {
//    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.7.20"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.1'
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.2.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:22.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.6.0'
    implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:21.1.0')
    implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.5.0')
    implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-ads-lite:22.6.0')
    implementation('com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0')
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
}
```